# Two-tier menu: shall I make a raw SQL query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Django 3.2.6

```
class Menu(NameUniqueMixin,
           ArchivedMixin,
           models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (MenuTypes.TOP.value, MenuTypes.TOP.value),
    ]

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)


class MenuLevelOne(NameUniqueMixin,
                   ArchivedMixin,
                   models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu,
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                             related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
                             related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss", )

    html = models.TextField(default="",
                            blank=False,
                            null=False)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,
                                       null=False,
                                       unique=True,
                                       db_index=True, )


class MenuLevelTwo(NameUniqueMixin,
                   ArchivedMixin,
                   models.Model):
    level_one = models.ForeignKey(MenuLevelOne,
                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                  related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
                                  related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss", )
    html = models.TextField(default="",
                            blank=False,
                            null=False)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,
                                       null=False,
                                       db_index=True, )
```

I'd like to make a tree-like menu.
Like this:

```
os
  \windows
  \linux
hardware
  \motherboards
  \sound cards
```

We can see here a two-tier menu.

I can't imagine what is the best way to select data from the database.

Of course, I am going to use a template as well. I'm going to make several queries to the database, then use a loop. And cache this all in the template.

In other words: I'm planning to organize an owfully inefficient piece of code here and conceal it using cache.

Or I'm also thinking of a custom SQL-query, which I don't like at all.

Could you tell me what is the bast way to select data from the database in this case? And how a rough draft of template for this meny may look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`prefetch_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to get all the `Menu` objects, and also fetch all the related sub-menus mapped to each menu above it.

Additionally, you can use [**`Prefetch`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) with a queryset to specify the order of the objects, in this case I assume would be based on `rank`, so:

```py
menu = Menu.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('app_label_menulevelone_related', queryset=MenuLevelOne.objects.order_by('rank'),
    Pefetch('app_label_menulevelone_related__app_label_menuleveltwo_related', queryset=MenuLevelTwo.objects.order_by('rank'),
)

#  Would work the same in the templates
for m in menu:
    print(m.type)
    for one in m.app_label_menulevelone_related.all():
        print(one.html)
        for two in one.app_label_menuleveltwo_related.all():
            print(two.html)
```

This will in total make 3 queries, one for `Menu`, one for `MenuLevelOne` and one for `MenuLevelTwo`. Just change the `app_label_*` to the actual related name you are using.